# Strange issue between Eclipse Mars and Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

**Some context**

I am creating a Spring Boot base code application that is in fact separated in three projects/modules:

**springbase-core**

contains:

- custom annotations
- custom exceptions
- custom generic Spring components
- model (entities)
- metamodels (generated by maven through the maven-processor-plugin)
- utils

depends on: nothing

**springbase-data**

contains:

- data related annotations
- services
- repositories
- data related util classes

depends on: springbase-core

**springbase-web**

- controllers
- form classes
- filters
- listeners
- interceptors
- JSPs
- JSP Tags
- etc.

depends on: springbase-data, springbase-core

The problem I am having is that if I have springbase-core in my Eclipse workspace, I'm not able to import metamodels in repository classes in springbase-data. **If I remove the springbase-core project (where metamodels reisde) from my Eclipse workspace, it works.**

I have also tried copying `springbase-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` from my `.m2` repository, directly at the root of my project (and taking care of adding it in .classpath), and **I was able to import metamodels**.

When opening `springbase-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` with WinZip, I can see the metamodels. Building `springbase-core` with Maven also shows the generated metamodels under /target/metamodel as configured in my pom.xml.

Looks like a glitch between Eclipse and Maven.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mars is actually pretty old. Both Neon and Oxygen have been released since, and the team is working on Photon now. I'd try the latest Eclipse if that's an option.

Comment: I think the glitch is the age of your Eclipse as already mentioned. I recommend to upgrade to at least Oxygen...

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version of Eclipse is not an option. I work in a corporate environment where all development tools must go through a rigorous approval process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to my problem: Right click on all projects, click on `Maven`, and then `Disable Workspace Resolution`.

That way Maven is going to look for the dependency only from `.m2`, regardless of what's in my workspace.